SQLAlchemy Base Model does not include the metadata all the time
I have a really strange issue. When running my main app :
def setup_app() -> FastAPI:
    """Initialize fastapi app."""
    setup_logging(logging.DEBUG)

    init_db(engine)


def init_db(engine) -> None: 
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

All the relevant tables are created, and the metadata attribute of the Base class is well populated.
This is not the case when i run my tests, where the entry point to initialize the db is here:
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db():
    delete_all_tables(engine)
    init_db(engine)

I really can't figure out what is happening under the hood which explain my the Base is differently populated.

Please add the code where you define models.
